# ASP.net navbar with bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-4

Good evening every one .
i would like to add an image near a navbar , but i'm not able to imitate the code propose by bootstrap  , because ASP.net use helpers of razor while in bootstrap web site there use diretly an html code.

please how could i adapt this in ASP.net

Answer (score 0):

> You should try following code instead of the HTML of bootstrap,
>   where imagepath is your image path.

Razor Syntax Rules for C#:

1. Razor code blocks are enclosed in @{ ... }
2. Inline expressions (variables and functions) start with @
3. C# code is case sensitive
4. Variables are declared with the var keyword
5. Code statements end with semicolon
6. Strings are enclosed with quotation marks
7. C# files have the extension .cshtml

   ```
   @model YourProject.Models.ImageModel
   @{ 
       imagePath= "xyz/xyz.jpg"
   }

   @if(imagePath != ""){
       <img src="@imagePath" alt="Image Name" width="200px" />
   }
   ```

> If you take image path from model then you try following code:

```
@model YourProject.Models.ImageModel


@if(Model.Photo != null && Model.Photo != ""){
      <img src="@Url.Content(@Model.Photo)" alt="@Model.AlternateText" />
}
```

If you don't understand then please refer following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/9-working-with-images